# Firebase increment key to avoid push

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i've little problem regarding firebase auto generated key via push().
i want to replace push auto generated key like in MySQL 0001,0002,0003,0004,0005

[Here is image for firebase auto generated key Click this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC5R0.jpg)

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
            Firebase ref=new Firebase(config_firebaseurl.FIREBASE_URL);

        String address=Address.getText().toString().trim();
            String license_no=licenseno.getText().toString().trim();


            personal_information per=new personal_information();
            per.setYear(getYear);
            per.setMonth(getMonth);
            per.setDay(getDate);
            per.setAddress(address);
            per.setState(state);
            per.setLicenseno(license_no);
            per.setFirstName(fname);
            per.setLastName(lname);
            per.setGender(getgender);
            per.setmobileNo(phoneno); 



            ref.child("personal_information").push().setValue(per);
            Intent i=new Intent(personal_information_handler.this, means_of_transport_handler.class);
            startActivity(i);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Information Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

I want to auto generated key in 0001,0002,0003 in this form .

Answer (score 1):

I'd not recommned doing so, but as workaround you can store like this:

```
ref.child("personal_information").child(incrementedId).setValue(per)
```

but in this case you need to know the last value each time you saving new data.

Comment: for example. i've multiple ref.child("personal_information").push().setVa‌​lue(per) ref.child("accounts").push().setValue(per) ref.child("department").push().setValue(per)
if you said you'd recommend so that i want that same push id will go for above 3 childs that is personal_info, accounts,departments
that's what i want so that if i retrieve data i can retrieve multiple data from single push key.